# Frequency of two columns counting NAs in one column as zero frequency

Tags: r, data.table, frequency

**Part 1**   I have the following data table. I want to make a new column which contains the number of occurrences of each `id` where there is any style value, except for `NA`. The main problem is that I don't know how to deal with the `NA`. Currently, when `NA` is present I get a frequency of 1.

```
id    style   
1     A    
1     A    
2     A    
2     B    
3     NA    
4     A    
4     C   
5     NA
```

I tried using the following, but it still counts `NA` values

```
dt[, allele_count := .N, by = list(pat_id, style)]
```

The desired data table would be as follows:

```
id    style   count
1     A       2
1     A       2
2     A       2
2     B       2
3     NA      0
4     A       4
4     B       4
4     B       4
4     C       4
5     NA      0
```

**Part2** I would also like to be able to add another column which would have the number of occurrences of each `id` with a certain style value.

```
id    style   count2
1     A       2
1     A       2
2     A       1
2     B       1
3     NA      0
4     A       1
4     B       2
4     B       2
4     C       1
5     NA      0
```

**Bonus Question**: Instead of looking at how many times an `id` occurs with a given `style` value as in **Part2** , How can you calculate the number of **different** `style` values for each `id`, as follows.

```
id    style   count3
1     A       1
1     A       1
2     A       2
2     B       2
3     NA      0
4     A       3
4     B       3
4     B       3
4     C       3
5     NA      0
```

Comment: No sure about the first count... what if, for instance, there's another id = 3 with style B, can you add the expected result with this example ? (also check your initial data.table since it doesn't have four id=4...)

Comment: The expected output does not match the input given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possibility.  Basically we use a row subset to assign the new columns, then replace the `NA` values in all three new columns with zero at the end.

```
nna <- !is.na(dt$style) ## so we don't have to call it four times
dt[nna, count := .N, by = id][nna, count2 := .N, by = .(id, style)][
    nna, count3 := uniqueN(style), by = id][!nna, names(dt)[3:5] := 0L]
```

which results in

```
   id style count count2 count3
1:  1     A     2      2      1
2:  1     A     2      2      1
3:  2     A     2      1      2
4:  2     B     2      1      2
5:  3    NA     0      0      0
6:  4     A     2      1      2
7:  4     C     2      1      2
8:  5    NA     0      0      0
```

Or you can simplify this down to the following, then reorder the columns if necessary.

```
dt[nna, c("count", "count3") := .(.N, uniqueN(style)), by = id][
    nna, count2 := .N, by = .(id, style)][!nna, names(dt)[3:5] := 0L]
```

Note that this method is very similar to the other posted answer.  I am not sure which of the two is the preferred method, row subset or `if()` statement.

Comment: That is fine too! Thx!

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution :

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5),
                 style=c('A','A','A','B',NA,'A','C',NA))

# count = number of ids having ALL styles defined
dt[, count := if(any(is.na(style))) 0L else .N, by = id]
# count2 = number of id-style occurrences (0 if style = NA)
dt[, count2 := if(is.na(style)) 0L else .N, by = .(id, style)]


> dt
   id style count count2
1:  1     A     2      2
2:  1     A     2      2
3:  2     A     2      1
4:  2     B     2      1
5:  3    NA     0      0
6:  4     A     2      1
7:  4     C     2      1
8:  5    NA     0      0
```

**BONUS:**

```
dt[, count3 := uniqueN(na.omit(style)), by = id]

> dt
   id style count count2 count3
1:  1     A     2      2      1
2:  1     A     2      2      1
3:  2     A     2      1      2
4:  2     B     2      1      2
5:  3    NA     0      0      0
6:  4     A     2      1      2
7:  4     C     2      1      2
8:  5    NA     0      0      0
```

Comment: `ifelse` should be saved for cases with condition vectors > 1. `any(..)` will always produce a logical of length `1`. In this case `if(any(is.na(style))) 0L else .N` is most likely the better control flow. But it may be open to debate for a case where they both happen to work, like this one.

Comment: In this case the results are exactly the same (I used ifelse function on purpose because I don't like one-line if-statements). Do you think ifelse is less efficient ?

Comment: I think it is more "correct". But I break the canonical rules all the time. The two statements behave differently, as many newer users may see them as interchangeable.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I admit when I first time faced ifelse on R, I was misled by it as well... I'm going to change it

Comment: Or you can avoid it altogether `dt[, count := sum(!is.na(style)), id][,count2 := sum(count != 0), by= .(id, style)][]`

Comment: Yep, but I changed ifelse to if for the sake of understandability, this is probably more difficult to get :D

Comment: Added the bonus answer

Comment: An `id` which corresponds to an `NA` should yield a frequency of `0` in `count3` because there is no `style` value for that `id`.